# How to obtain UA metrics data from Google Analytics Data API (GA4)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've faced a comparability problem while migrating from Reporting API V4 to Data API V1 (Beta). Some old (UA) metrics became not available.
Several of them are computable at client side.
For example:

```
 avgSessionDuration(ga:avgSessionDuration) = userEngagementDuration(ga:sessionDuration) / sessions(ga:sessions)
 pageViewsPerSession(ga:pageviewsPerSession) = screenPageViews(ga:pageviews) / sessions(ga:sessions)
```

The question is: How to obtain equivalent data for listed below UA metrics using Data API V1?

```
ga:uniquePageviews 
ga:avgTimeOnPage
```

Comment: Universal analytics and GA4 are two totally different systems your not going to be able to convert a report.  You need to make new reports designed for GA4.

Comment: Agree. I want to create GA4 report with aggregated total data about uniquePageviews and avgTimeOnPage. @DaImTo, it possible to extract this data from the available GA4 metrics? If so, how?

Comment: No it is not GA4 does not have uniquePageviews or avgTimeOnPage

Answer (score 0):

Universal analytics and GA4 are two totally different systems your not going to be able to convert a report. You need to make new reports designed for GA4.

GA4 does not have uniquePageviews or avgTimeOnPage

You should check [API Dimensions & Metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/api-schema) to find the current list of dimensions and metrics available with Ga4.

Remember Ga4 is [Event based](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9322688) not page view based.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be available. check this page for GA4 equivalents:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/migration-api-schema-mapping

Im getting the data succesfully by using:

Dimension: fullPageUrl

Metrics: eventCount, userEngagementDuration